# PHP Extend class with static variables and functions

Tags: php, inheritance, static

I have a problem, well, many but this one in particular involves the following:

I have a Database connection class that I've constructed - carefully taking bits and pieces from what I know and from posts such as this one - that utilizes a static variable for a connection.  Here is a snippet from the class:

```
class DatabaseConnection {
private static $dbconn;
private static $conn;
private $user;
private $pass;

public static function getInstance ( ) {
    if ( !self::$dbconn )   {
        self::$dbconn = new self();
    }
    return self::$dbconn;
}

...
...

public function getConnection()
{

    if ( $this->conn ) 
    { 
        return $this->conn ;
    }
    if (!$this->detailsSet) return null;
    try {       
        self::$conn = new PDO ($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->options);
        foreach ( $attributes as $k => $v ) {
            self::$conn -> setAttribute ( constant ( "PDO::{$k}" ), constant ( "PDO::{$v}" ) ) ;
        }
        return self::$conn ;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        return null;    
    }
}
...
...

}
```

What I'm trying to do now is to extend this class in order to get specific as to the operations that can be performed. For instance, I have a class called UserRecordUpdater. Here is a snippet:

```
class UserRecordUpdater extends DatabaseConnection
{
public static function getInstance ( ) {
    if ( !self::$dbconn )   {
        self::$dbconn = new self();
    }
    return self::$dbconn;
}

public function addUser($newUser)
{
...
}
...
...
}
```

so if you can't decipher what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to be able to create some new classes (such as the child class above) that would utilize the existing static connection created within the parent class, but would have their own specific set of operations.

Here is how I'm calling this code from my main script:

```
include_once('./library/DatabaseConnection.php');
include_once('./library/UserRecordUpdater.php');

...

$userUpdater = UserRecordUpdater::getInstance();

...

$userUpdater->addUser($someuser);
```

please assume that the code between the `...`'s is working ok...

Now, all this said, I am getting the error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access  property UserRecordUpdater::$dbconn in /path/UserRecordUpdater.php`

The error is pointing to the line: `if ( !self::$dbconn )` in the child class.

Now, before pointing out the obvious (which is that $dbconn is in the parent so I should be using `parent::$dbconn`, note that I have tried this and I know it won't work. It is definitely my lack of understanding around inheritance combined with my lack of understanding of static variables. But at least hopefully my explanation is clear enough to get an answer as to what is the "right" way to do this (or at least one right way).

Comment: Someone actually posted a comment that I think is leading me in the right direction - that I should use `protected` instead of `private` in my property declarations within the parent class. After reading up a little, I'm thinking this might help. Will update soon.

Comment: I think this is working, I'm getting some other errors now, but I believe that this WAS the problem I was encountering. I should have been using PROTECTED. From reading online I saw that PROTECTED was used within parent classes to allow child classes to use their properties using `$this->` but I wasn't aware that this also was the case for STATIC variables. Mystery commenter who posted and then deleted their comment.... THANKS!